# How To Output results from a table where the data does not exist in the other table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which places a client on a 'grid' with x and y coordinates from -10 to 10.

I need to select the grid sections which there are no clients. I have tried using `NOT EXIST` but it does not show me the data I need. i.e if empty gird section was at -1-8 it would not select it.

I have tried this way below:

Also I know this was not a well worded question but would appreciate any tips on how to rod it better...

```
SELECT * 
FROM grid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM client 
    WHERE client.x = grid.x
    ANDclient.y = grid.y
);
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/94545/2) to show my environment and tables.

Comment: Your query looks correct, what's the problem with it? Can you show the expected result with the data you posted?

Comment: `OR` should be `AND`.

Comment: With `OR`, you're only returning grid elements where there's no client in the same row or column.

Comment: It does not show results where the empty grid section would be -1-8 for example. Only the grid sections that are defined in the table

Comment: A join can't return rows that aren't in either table. The `grid` table needs to contain all grid sections.

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: Is it possible to generate each grid section or would I need to type in eachindividual grid section (would take me forever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grid` table needs to have a row for each point in the grid. You only have rows for the points on the diagonals.

```
INSERT INTO grid VALUES
(1, -10, -10),
(2, -10, -9),
(3, -10, -8),
...
(11, -10, 0),
...
(21, -10, 10),
(22, -9, -10),
(23, -9, -9),
...
```

If you make the `id` column `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can automate this with the following query:

```
WITH numbers AS 
    SELECT -10 AS x
    UNION
    SELECT -9
    UNION
    SELECT -8
    UNION
    ...
    UNION
    SELECT 0
    UNION 
    SELECT 1
    ...
    UNION
    SELECT 10) AS numbers
INSERT INTO grid (x, y)
SELECT n1.x, n2.x
FROM numbers
CROSS JOIN numbers
```